# Is it allowed to answer multiple questions from the same user?

Tags: discussion, answers

If I monitor a specific tag and that tag does not have a lot of people that ask questions, is it a problem if I answer the same people more than once?

I mean, if a user asked 5 questions in 5 days for example, is it a problem if I answer all their questions?

Answer (score 12):

No, this is no problem at all. Remember that you're not only answering for the author of the question, but for all future readers of that post which might have the same problem. Stack Exchange's main focus is the *content*, not the people who post it.

Answer (score 11):

> Is it a problem if I answer same people more than once?

No, it is not. However, you might want to watch the question and your answer quality. Else, it might look as the two of you are trying to farm some reputation from low-quality questions and answers.

The might find problems when the two of you interact too much, and only with the two of you: that might trigger some serial-voting detection. The script might reverse the votes.

Comment: Is that last sentence correct that a mod can reverse a reversal? I've got no particular reason to doubt it but I've never seen any mention of it anywhere.

Comment: @PeterJ it's not a thing...